# Is there a way to filter, so that I only get reactions where SUMATRIPTAN was listed as suspect drug?

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I'm trying to get the number of reactions for a certain drug, but only where the drug was classified as suspect drug (drugcharacterization=1).

I tried: [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(*exists*:(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact)+AND+receivedate:([20040101+TO+20170630])+AND+patient.drug.drugcharacterization=1)+AND+(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name:%22SUMATRIPTAN%22)](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(_exists_:(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact)+AND+receivedate:([20040101+TO+20170630])+AND+patient.drug.drugcharacterization=1)+AND+(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name:%22SUMATRIPTAN%22))
and [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(*exists*:(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact)+AND+receivedate:([20040101+TO+20170630])+AND+(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name:%22SUMATRIPTAN%22),that](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(_exists_:(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact)+AND+receivedate:([20040101+TO+20170630])+AND+(patient.drug.openfda.generic_name:%22SUMATRIPTAN%22),that) outcoes aren't different.
In this way,I can't get the number of reactions for a certain drug, but only where the drug was classified as suspect drug (drugcharacterization=1).

Is there a way to filter, so that I only get reactions where SUMATRIPTAN was listed as suspect drug?